# How to prevent following img cursor if it's outside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If user moves the cursor outside the block #mouse-pointer, it disappears under the menu and other divs. Want to make image follow the cursor only when it is inside the block with id #mouse-pointer.

```
$(function (){
    $(window).mousemove(function(event) {
        $('#mouse-pointer').css({
            'top' : event.pageY -100 + 'px',
            'left' : event.pageX -100 + 'px'
        });
    }); 
});
```

html

```
<style>
#my-container{
position: relative;
width:100vw;
height: 600px;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
overflow-y: hidden !important;
cursor: none;
}
</style>
<div id="my-container">
<div id="lg-top-image"  data-src="img/image_above.jpg"></div>
<div id="lg-bottom-image" data-src="img/image_below.jpg"></div>
<figure id="mouse-pointer"></figure>
</div>
```

Comment: So bind mousemove event to the element you want, not the window: `$('#my-container').mousemove(...);`

Comment: Thanks. It works! `$("#my-container").mousemove(function(event)`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be adding the event listener on the window, if you want the event to trigger only from a certain element. Do this instead:

```
$('#my-container').on('mousemove', function() {
   $('#mouse-pointer').css({
        'top' : event.pageY -100 + 'px',
        'left' : event.pageX -100 + 'px'
    });
});
```